# How to Verify Tab Names in JTabbedPane

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane

I am using a `JideTabbedPane`. which extends `JTabbedPane`. After a user edits the name of a tab, I want to check whether the name meets certain criteria, e.g. the name must not be an empty string. If it doesn't meet the criteria, the old name of the tab should be used.

I used a `TabEditingListener` to try to accomplish this task, but it didn't work. Here is what I wrote:

```
  addTabEditingListener(new TabEditingListener() {
    public void editingStopped(TabEditingEvent event) {
      if (event.getNewTitle().isEmpty()) {
        setTitleAt(event.getTabIndex(), event.getOldTitle());
      }
    }
  }
```

Any ideas will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You might want to specify the 'did not work' part. Is your listener never called ? Is the title in the event not set ? Do you get any exceptions ? ...

Comment: @Robin The listener gets called, but the title never gets set. No exceptions. Nothing happens.

Comment: did you have got the same EDT issue as in the [JideForum](http://www.jidesoft.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=18&t=12472&p=61402&hilit=JideTabbedPane#p61402)

Comment: @mKorbel I didn't get an EDT issue.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the `JideTabbedPane` so there might be better solutions and mechanisms. But the `JTabbedPane#setTitleAt` method which I guess is called after editing the title fires a `PropertyChangeEvent` for the `indexForTitle` property according to the source code. You can listen for that event and perform the validation.

Answer (score 0):

You should have an else statement pretty much saying that if it isn't invalid, set the text as what they entered.